# Better tagging / taxonomy reference widget

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax, entities

The *Term Reference* field type has three stock widget types:

- Select List
- Check boxes/radio buttons
- Autocomplete term widget (tagging)

We need an alternative to the autocomplete widget that shows all existing terms in a vocabulary and allows users to enter another.

Here is a sample of what I'm looking for (I just made this in Firebug—I don't have a viable option yet). In this option, the vocabulary would include two terms, banana and pear, and the user could enter a different term.

[image: Sample UI for proposed widget]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Select (or other)](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module looks like provide similar UI.

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes
>   element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a
>   textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

Unfortunately it doesn't support Term References.

Try [Autocomplete](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) Deluxe module or [Chosen](http://drupal.org/project/chosen) module for better UI and functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to implement this without term references. The module does exactly what I need.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Great !

Comment: The new 7.3 branch of Select (or other) supports taxonomy terms and term reference fields. I've just tried the 7.3.x dev release from Nov 2015 and it worked as expected first time. The only slight issue is that, unlike the above screenshot, the "Other" text box is by default hidden until the "Other" checkbox is ticked, but that can be fixed easily by theming.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this powerful module [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)